# Test class for feed items in chatter for trigger increment

Tags: unit-test, trigger

```
trigger CountChatterPostsOnCase on FeedItem (before insert, after Insert ) {
    String caseKeyPrefix = Case.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
    set<ID> caseIDs = new set<ID>();

    for (FeedItem f : trigger.new){
        String parentId = f.parentId;

        if(parentId != null && parentId.startsWith(caseKeyPrefix) && f.Visibility == 'AllUsers'){
            caseIDs.add(f.parentId);
        }
    }

    if(!caseIDs.IsEmpty()){
        List<case> cslist = [Select f1 , f2 from Case where id = :caseIDs];
        for (case cs:cslist) {
            cs.f1 = cs.f1 == null? 1 : cs.f1 + 1;
            cs.f2 = cs.f2 == null? 1 : cs.f2 + 1;
        }

        update cslist;
    }
}
```

I have trigger for chatter feeditems to increment post in chatter...

How I test the class:

```
@isTest
Public with sharing class CountChatterPostsOnCaseTest {

    Public static testmethod testCountChatterPostsOnCase()
    {
        Contact cont = new Contact();
            cont.NTID__c ='test1';
            cont.Last Name ='demo';
            cont.Country__c ='ABC';
            cont.Email ='abc@xyc.com';
            cont.Segments__c ='Business';
            cont.BU_name__c ='test1';
            cont.SPU__c =='Canada';

        insert cont;

        Case cs = new case ();
            cs.contact name = cont.id;
            cs.Type_Oyster__c = 'Ineed';
            cs.Type = 'Test1';
            cs.Request_Sub_Type__c ='test2';
            cs.Workflow__c ='test3';
            cs.Status = 'test4';
            cs.Pending_With__c ='test2';
            cs.Case Origin = 'Email';


        insert cs;

        FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
        post.body = '[Welcome to test Knowledge]';
        Post.parentid = cs.Id;       

        insert post;
    }
}
```

The test class above is not covering 75% code coverage.

Comment: It appears you are missing the trigger that you are trying to test. Or have mixed it with a test class. Can you check the code you have posted in the question.

Comment: @Daniel .. i have mixed trigger in the test class .. can you help to implement test class for this trigger ..

Comment: The example code in your question doesn't make any sense. It starts out like a test case and then uses trigger context variables like trigger.new.

Comment: yeah ur right @DanielBallinger ..Above code made any sense for it .. if yes plz can u help me or guide me how to write   test class for below trigger ..

Comment: What have you tried so far? As you stuck on a particular part? SFSE isn't really about writing your test cases for you. There is a good discussion of this in [Need Help With Test Class](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/18816/102)